# How to set a column to be sorted on page load dynamically using DataTables.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

Iam using Asp mvc. I have this table,which is a dataTables,

in my page, columns of the table sometimes appear or not, depending on the users authotrization. 
e.g i have this table with checkbox(it appears dynamically and is on the left-most column), that i want to be not sortable.
i also wanted to sort the first column in the left on default. 
So whether, checkbox appears or not, i want the first non-check box column to be sortable.
Is this possible?.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been here for long, hopefully you got it resolved. 
I am not sure I get it clearly, but my advise is that you look at this page for ideas on how you can control sorting using datatables.net:

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/sorting_control.html

If you use one of the DataTools you can even control which columns show or give users the opportunity to select the columns they want to see. 
Look at the examples here: 
http://www.datatables.net/examples/

Answer (score 1):

By this code you can sort individual columns on datatables by adding class 'sort-desc' or 'sort-asc' for sorting ascending and descending on page load

```
$('.dom-table').each(function(index) {
        var sort_column=$('.dom-table thead tr').children().index('.sort-desc');
        var sort_oper='desc';
        if(sort_column < 0)
        {
            var sort_column=$('.dom-table thead tr').children().index('.sort-asc');
            sort_oper='asc';
            if(sort_column < 0)
            {
                sort_column=0;
            }
        }
        $(this).dataTable({
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "aaSorting": [[sort_column,sort_oper]],
    });
});
```

I have not tested this code but it should work.